# DevExtreme DataGrid Post datagrid with form at once in ASP .NET Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, devextreme

I'm having problem with using `DataGrid` control DevExtreme library for ASP.NET Core.
I have razor page inside my project to add some people with phone numbers to my project.
The header of the form getting some First name, last name, birth date and etc. and the `DataGrid` is responsible for add, edit and remove phone numbers.
But when I implemented the `DataGrid` page URLs my page binding my my ViewModel get broken.
I can't get my header data on posting form isn't there any way to post `DataGrid` values with the form itself?
PartyViewModel:

```
public class PartyViewModel
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; } = Guid.Empty;
    public string FirstName { get; set; } = string.Empty;
    public string LastName { get; set; } = string.Empty;
    [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    public DateTime? Birthdate { get; set; }
    public PartyType Type { get; set; } = PartyType.Unknown;
    public List<PartyPhoneViewModel> PhoneNumbers { get; } = new();
}
```

PartyPhoneViewModel:

```
public class PartyPhoneViewModel
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string PhoneNumber { get; set; } = string.Empty;
    public PartyPhoneTypeEnum Type { get; set; } = PartyPhoneTypeEnum.Unknown;
}
```

PartyPage.cshtml:

```
@inject Microsoft.AspNetCore.Antiforgery.IAntiforgery Xsrf

<style>
    form {
        display: block;
        margin-top: 0em;
    }
</style>

<script>
    function grid_dataSource_beforeSend(op, ajax) {
        ajax.headers = {
            RequestVerificationToken: "@Xsrf.GetAndStoreTokens(Model.HttpContext).RequestToken"
        };
    }
</script>

<form method="post" asp-page-handler="Party">
    <div class="container my-0 my-sm-1 my-md-3 my-lg-5">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-12 p-3   col-md-8 offset-md-2 p-md-4   col-lg-6 offset-lg-3 p-lg-5   bg-light border border-2 rounded-3 shadow-lg">
                <fieldset>
                    <legend>
                        @(pageTitle)
                    </legend>

                    <hr />

                    <partial name="PartialViews/_DisplayPageMessages" />

                    @* <input type="hidden" value="@(Model.ReturnUrl)" /> *@

                    <div class="row">

                        <div class="col-6 mb-3">
                            <label asp-for="ViewModel.FirstName" class="form-label"></label>

                            <input asp-for="ViewModel.FirstName" class="form-control" dir="ltr" />

                            <span asp-validation-for="ViewModel.FirstName" class="text-danger"></span>
                        </div>

                        <div class="col-6 mb-3">
                            <label asp-for="ViewModel.LastName" class="form-label"></label>

                            <input asp-for="ViewModel.LastName" class="form-control" dir="ltr" />

                            <span asp-validation-for="ViewModel.LastName" class="text-danger"></span>
                        </div>

                        <div class="col-6 mb-3">
                            <label asp-for="ViewModel.Birthdate" class="form-label"></label>

                            <input asp-for="ViewModel.Birthdate" class="form-control" dir="ltr" />

                            <span asp-validation-for="ViewModel.Birthdate" class="text-danger"></span>
                        </div>

                        <div class="col-6 mb-3">
                            <label asp-for="ViewModel.Type" class="form-label"></label>

                            <select asp-for="ViewModel.Type" class="form-control form-select" asp-items="Html.GetEnumSelectList<PartyType>()"></select>

                            <span asp-validation-for="ViewModel.Type" class="text-danger"></span>
                        </div>

                        <div class="col-12 mb-3">

                            @(
                                Html.DevExtreme().DataGrid<PartyPhoneModel>()
                                    .ShowBorders(true)
                                    .ID("grdPartyPhones")
                                    .ColumnAutoWidth(true)
                                    .RepaintChangesOnly(true)
                                    .AllowColumnResizing(true)
                                    .TwoWayBindingEnabled(true)
                                    .ColumnResizingMode(ColumnResizingMode.NextColumn)
                                    .DataSource(ds => ds.RemoteController()
                                            .CacheRawData(false)
                                            .LoadUrl(Url.Page(null, "GridData")) // access to the GridData handler defined in the OnGetGridData method in the page model
                                            .UpdateUrl(Url.Page(null, "GridRow")) // access to the GridRow handler defined in the OnPutGridRow method in the page model
                                            .InsertUrl(Url.Page(null, "GridRow")) // access to the GridRow handler defined in the OnPostGridRow method in the page model
                                            .DeleteUrl(Url.Page(null, "RemoveRow")) // access to the RemoveRow handler defined in the On method in the page model
                                            .OnBeforeSend("grid_dataSource_beforeSend") // passes an antiforgery token
                                            .Key("Id")
                                     )
                                    .Columns(column =>
                                    {
                                        column.AddFor(x => x.PhoneNumber);
                                        column.AddFor(x => x.Type).Lookup(lookup => lookup
                                            .DataSource(Html.GetEnumSelectList<PartyPhoneTypeEnum>()
                                            .Select(i => new { Value = int.Parse(i.Value), Text = i.Text }))
                                            .ValueExpr("Value")
                                            .DisplayExpr("Text"));
                                    })
                                    .Editing(edit => edit
                                        .RefreshMode(GridEditRefreshMode.Full)
                                        .AllowAdding(true)
                                        .AllowDeleting(true)
                                        .AllowUpdating(true)
                                        .UseIcons(true)
                                    )
                                )

                        </div>

                    </div>

                    <div class="mb-3 row">
                        <div class="col-6 text-center">
                            <button type="submit" class="col-12 btn btn-primary mx-1">@(Labels.CreateNew)</button>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-6 text-center">
                            <button type="reset" class="col-12 btn btn-secondary mx-1">@(Labels.Reset)</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </fieldset>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

</form>
```

and the last part PartyPage.cshtml.cs:

```
public class PartyPageModel : NGBasePageModel
{
    #region Fields And Properties

    [BindProperty]
    public PartyViewModel ViewModel { get; set; } = new();

    #endregion Fields And Properties

    #region ctor

    public PartyPageModel(IServiceProvider serviceProvider) : base(serviceProvider)
    {

    }

    #endregion ctor

    #region Page Actions

    public override async Task OnGetAsync()
    {
        await base.OnGetAsync();
        if (Id == Guid.Empty)
            ViewModel = new();
        else
        {
            var party =
                await ServiceProvider
                    .GetRequiredService<IPartyBusiness>()
                        .FetchPartyByIdAsync(Id, true);

            if (party != null)
            {
                ViewModel = party.Adapt<PartyViewModel>();
                foreach (var item in party.PhoneNumbers)
                {
                    ViewModel.PhoneNumbers.Add(item.Adapt<PartyPhoneViewModel>());
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostParty([FromServices] IPartyBusiness partyBusiness)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            return Page();
        var result = await partyBusiness.AddOrUpdateParty(ViewModel);
        if (!result)
            return Page();
        return RedirectToPage("/");
    }

    #endregion Page Actions

    #region Grid Actions

    public IActionResult OnGetGridData(DataSourceLoadOptions loadOptions)
    {
        return new JsonResult(
            DataSourceLoader.Load(
                ViewModel.PhoneNumbers, loadOptions));
    }

    public IActionResult OnPostGridRow(Guid key, string values)
    {
        InsertRow(key, values);
        return new OkResult();
    }

    public IActionResult OnPutGridRow(Guid key, string values)
    {
        UpdateRow(key, values);
        return new OkResult();
    }

    public IActionResult OnDeleteRemoveRow(Guid key)
    {
        RemoveRow(key);
        return new OkResult();
    }

    #endregion Grid Actions

    #region Grid Row Methods

    void InsertRow(Guid key, string values)
    {
        var phone = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<PartyPhoneViewModel>(values);
        if (phone == null) return;
        ViewModel.PhoneNumbers.Add(phone);
    }

    void UpdateRow(Guid key, string values)
    {
        var jobj = JObject.Parse(values);

        if (ViewModel.PhoneNumbers.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == key) is not PartyPhoneViewModel partyPhonevm) return;

        if (jobj.ContainsKey(nameof(partyPhonevm.PhoneNumber)) && jobj.Value<string>(nameof(partyPhonevm.PhoneNumber)) is string phone)
            partyPhonevm.PhoneNumber = phone;

        if (jobj.ContainsKey(nameof(partyPhonevm.Type)) && jobj.Value<PartyPhoneTypeEnum>(nameof(partyPhonevm.Type)) is PartyPhoneTypeEnum phoneType)
            partyPhonevm.Type = phoneType;
    }

    void RemoveRow(Guid key)
    {
        if (key != Guid.Empty) return;
        if (ViewModel.PhoneNumbers.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == key) is PartyPhoneViewModel partyPhoneVM)
            ViewModel.PhoneNumbers.Remove(partyPhoneVM);
    }

    #endregion Grid Row Methods
```

Thank you
Regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> when I implemented the DataGrid page URLs my page binding my my
> ViewModel get broken.

I checked the codes and tried to repo the issue on myside, I could never bind value to PartyPhoneViewModel

```
public class PartyViewModel
{
   public List<PartyPhoneViewModel> PhoneNumbers { get; } = new();
}
```

The public setter is required for model binding,here's a related [issue](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/38243) on github

If it's not your issue,please explain the trouble you're facing with  to me

Comment: Thank you, but in this case public setter also doesn't make the binding working :(